# How can i get the html of a cross-domain webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, yql

I am developing a webpage where i need to get the html content of another cross-domain site. While google i got to know about YQL. But i am not familiar with `YQl`. Can we solve this problem using `Javascript` or `Jquery`?

Your suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Is that other cross domain site under your control? Can you change its responses?

Comment: no that is not in my control.

Comment: being honest is those cases, it is better to do that in the server not in the browser, for example when I use PHP and I need to do something like that I usually use "file_get_contents('http://www.website.com/')" and then send the information back to the user.

Comment: I know about Same origin policy.

Comment: The only way to do it all in JavaScript is [HTTP access control (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), which requires the requested page to permit your website (or all other sites)

Comment: @mechdeveloper how can we do similar in asp.net?

Comment: @OnlyR, if the other site is not in your control, you cannot do it on the client side.. You will have to do it on the server side.

Comment: @mahesh how??Please provide the link for reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) class on server side to read the other page.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string result = client.DownloadString(address);
```

That downloads the whole page output.

Answer (score 0):

> But i am not familiar with YQl

It is a web service.

> Can we solve this problem using Javascript or Jquery?

You can use JavaScript to access YQL. You can't replace YQL with client-side JavaScript.